# CNAME start with number (ex. 7dpeias3jim6) not working

Tags: azure, dns, blogger

I tried to setup custom domain in the Blogger. Blogger provided 2 CNAME to add in my DNS. 1 of the CNAME provided is started with number (ex. 7dpeias3jim6). I have added the CNAME in the Azure DNS but it is not reflecting. See here: https://who.is/dns/blog.dailytelwireless.com. That is the reason Blogger can not verify & Setup Custom domain. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `CNAME` can start with any character, so it starting with a number is not the cause of any problem, except bugs in software of course. But your question is not related to programming, so offtopic here. If you have issues with provider Blogger your first action should be to contact them and ask for guidance.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not in blogger but in the azure dns setting. when I am adding cname start with alphabet its working fine but only problem when the cname start with number.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TXT` verification instead of `CNAME`, there is more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=cname%2Cazurecli#dns-record-types

[image]

[image]

Create a TXT record that has just the `Value` portion in it, this is the `Custom Domain Verification ID`